# Clogging when spraying lacquer with a gun

Tags: finishing

My spray gun gets clogged or sticky between coats. Do I really have to take apart the gun?

How do I keep the spray gun usable between lacquer coats?

Comment: How long are you waiting between coats?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I really have to take apart tge gun?

Not between coats no, but you should be doing a complete stripdown and thorough cleaning after each spraying session in case that's not already part of your routine.

> How do I keep the spray gun usable between lacquer coats.

Shoot straight thinners/solvent through the gun between coats to flush out the system.

Spraying through with the appropriate solvent is fairly standard practice when spraying any fast-drying paint or coating through a gun with any fine tolerances.

The easiest way to do this is if you have a spare paint cup or bottle that you can swap in, but if you don't you'll have to empty the diluted lacquer from the gun's receptacle to another container*, rinse, then fill with some solvent and shoot through.

If the problem is mostly at the tip of the nozzle you can sometimes get away with just brushing this using a stiffish brush wet with your solvent (be very careful if there is a projecting needle), then shooting just air through the gun to flush the nozzle. Repeating this once or twice gets most nozzles clean enough that they'll stay clear for the next coat but it depends on the equipment, and without any details of what you're using I can only guess at whether this might work with your gun.

---

*Never return it to the original container. Use something with a lid to prevent evaporation, and make sure it's spotlessly clean so you don't contaminate the lacquer.

Comment: please note: make sure you are using the proper ventilation and safety equipment. The solvent is much easier to breath in and 'hangs' in the air longer, so is easier to accumulate too much in the air. 

So, while I agree with Graphus completely, I would remind folks to be safe.